# Log4net not creating log file in web api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, log4net

Log4net not creating log file in web api project.

Here is the config file.

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
  <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
<appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Temp\logs" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Global.asx

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        // Initialize log4net.
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
```

Assembly info file

```
   [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]
```

Comment: I can't recall if your website have access to the system Temp folder, have you tried placeing the log file under the App_Data folder ? set `<file value="C:\Temp\logs" />` to `<file value="App_Data\logs" />` and also give the IIS user write access to App_Data

Comment: its working after doing two things 

1) remove system.reflection  private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

2) add config file to web api project

Comment: I have the same issue with an asp.net web api where I was initializing the log4net in the AssemblyInfo.cs and was not working creating any logs. I had to do it in the Application_Start() in global.asax (  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();)